# Strange messages when suspending/hibernating

Tags: suspend, hibernate

While suspending or hibernating, a terminal is shown. Normally it's blank, but lately it's been showing messages like these:

```
[  429.276100] i2400m_usb 2-1.5:1.0: device reset on resume: reinitializing driver
[33773.933883] i2400m_usb 2-1.5:1.0: failed to suspend, will reset on resume
[XXXX24.329201] i2400m_usb 2-1.5:1.0: device rebooted: reinitializing driver
```

(I took a picture of it, since they don't stay up long, & couldn't read some of those last numbers because of a glare on the screen.)

A new line is added each time the computer wakes up, and the numbers in brackets grow larger each time. What does it mean?

Update: Since I upgraded to 13.04, there's been a new message:

```
[numbers] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to alloc_pages with GFP_KERNEL.Only 0 free buffers remaining.
```

This is on <strike>12.10</strike> 13.04 64-bit.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 12.10 64-bit; added that to the question.

Comment: @Rinzwind `syslog` file is no longer present in `/etc/var/`, instead is located at `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: What flavor of Ubuntu?  I've seen this happen on Gnome builds that don't use the Gnome-team PPA

Comment: It's just normal Ubuntu.